# Which entangled states have a zero entanglement negativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

On the Wikipedia page of [entanglement negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_(quantum_mechanics)), it is stated that the logarithmic negativity can be zero even if the state is entangled. What are the examples of entangled states that have a zero logarithmic negativity?

Comment: See bound entanglement or nondistillable entanglement

Answer (score 2):

Most entangled states have non-zero negativity. In particular, all entangled pure states have non-zero negativity, as well as all entangled states of two qubits or one qubit and one qutrit. If you want a concrete example, take the maximally entangled state
$$
\lvert\Omega\rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert00\rangle + \lvert 11\rangle)\ .
$$